# A Short Easy Addictive Riddle

Tags: riddle

I am a conjunction but with extra tea,

Good company to a wheeze and a pant,

I am one over a large key that locks,

And I think my head is on fire!

**What am I?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Cigarette Butt (Addictive)

I am a conjunction but with extra tea,

> Butt (Conjunction But with extra t)

Good company to a wheeze and a pant,

> Smoking causes wheezing and panting.

OP:

> "Puff" - a synonym of cigarette

I am one over a large key that locks,

> It filters the smoke.

OP:

> Above a Caps Lock (a large keyboard key) is a "Tab" - another synonym

And I think my head is on fire!

> Cigarette lit up.

Comment: Well done.  +1 Added a couple of explanations.

Comment: @ 3rd line: I tried to fit the "tab" all the time and I couldn't... Glad you explained that

Answer (score 4):

You are a

> welding torch (or a  oxydrogen blowpipe)
> [image]

because:

> I am a conjunction but with extra tea,  
> Good company to a
>   wheeze and a pant

could means

> the conjunction of two gasses (pant and wheeze meanings "breath") in a "T" conjuction ("tea" is pronounced as "T")

The key that locks is

> the valve

And my answer explain exactly why your head is on fire

Comment: Not bad but not the answer.  I am actually much more common than this.  I'm glad this one wasn't too easy after all!  +1  (there is also a clue in the title)

Comment: @BrentHackers  I'm not an able solver and I intended the addiction as the mix of two gases. But this thing in my answer is common for me :) thank you for the riddle, waiting for the right ansewer from someone!

Answer (score 2):

> Hookah (Addictive)

I am a conjunction but with extra tea,

> Could refer to a mix wherein tobacco is used or could be tea flavored hookah.

Good company to a wheeze and a pant,

> Smoking causes wheeze and pant

I am one over a large key that locks,

> Probably the valve in the setup.

And I think my head is on fire!

> The charcoals that burn above producing smoke that is passed through the water.